# Count the number of vowels and print them in a manner that string having more vowels come first

Tags: java

In,This code I've to "n" string. Then count the number of vowels in a string and print "n" number of string in a manner that a string having more vowels print first.

```
Sample Input:

3
My name
is
Paul Jonas

Sample Output:

Paul Jonas 4
My name 2
is 1
```

This is my attempt but I'cant process the output that a string having more vowel comes first

```
import java.util.*;
public class CountVowel {
    public static void  main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();

        int n;
        n = sc.nextInt();

        String str;

        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            str = sc.nextLine();
            word.add(str);
        }

        int arr[] = new int[3];
        int j = 0;
        for(String s:word){
            int count = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                if(s.charAt(i)=='A' || s.charAt(i)=='E' || s.charAt(i)=='I' || s.charAt(i)=='O'||s.charAt(i)=='U'
                || s.charAt(i)=='a' || s.charAt(i)=='e' || s.charAt(i)=='i' || s.charAt(i)=='o' || s.charAt(i)=='u'){

                    count++;

                }
            }
            arr[j] = count;
            j++;

        }

        int i = 0;
        for(String s: word){

            System.out.println(s+" "+arr[i]);
            i++;
        }



    }
}
```

So, I'm not getting my desired Output.

```
Input:

3
My name
is
Paul Jonas

Output I'm getting:

My name 2
is 1
Paul Jonas 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot solve your task without using the class [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), starting from defining a method counting the vowels in a word like below:

```
private static final String VOWELS = "aeiou";

public static int getCountVowels(String word) {
    int count = 0;
    char[] arr = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    for (char ch: arr) {
        if (VOWELS.indexOf(ch) != -1) { ++count; }
    }

    return count;
}
```

After you can create a `Map` of words and count of vowels like below:

```
String[] words = {"My name", "is", "Paul Jonas"};
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : words) { map.put(word, getCountVowels(word)); }
```

Then you have to order the map entries `key,value`  by value in reverse order of value and print them using `Collections`:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
    .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()));
```

Below the total code printing the expected result:

```
public class CountVowels {
    private static final String VOWELS = "aeiou";

    public static int getCountVowels(String word) {
        int count = 0;
        char[] arr = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for (char ch: arr) {
            if (VOWELS.indexOf(ch) != -1) { ++count; }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = {"My name", "is", "Paul Jonas"};
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (String word : words) { map.put(word, getCountVowels(word)); }

        map.entrySet().stream()
           .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
           .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Youll need to sort this based on the occurrences of the vowel, i suggest using a hashmap in conjunction with `Collections.sort` so you get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a Map.
`Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();`

Then you can sort it by value as mentioned in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61744606/11537839